# Set the visibility of the ascx in aspx.page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my master page I have ContentPlaceHolder for left content,right content see below:

```
<body class="software">
    <form id="form1" name="MyFrom" runat="server"> 
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" ></telerik:RadScriptManager>    
        <div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <menu:main id="mainMenu" runat="server"/>
                <div id="leftCol">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LeftContent" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>                               
                <div id="rightCol">                                                 
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="RightContent" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>        
    </form>
</body>
```

On my aspx page I have on the left hand side TreeView for each of every node in the TreeView I want to load a different ascx which going to change only the right hand side of the page
 I want to set visible false and load other ascx the issue it's throwing me an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I access the ascx on the page on the right way???

```
Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Page.FindControl("/Controls/Reports/rptReport.ascx").Visible = False
```

That's what I have on the rptReport.ascx:

```
<%--Right Side--%>
<div id="rightCol" >
    <div class="elementHeader" id="elementHeader">
        <span class="text"><asp:Label ID="lblReports" runat="server" Text="Reports"></asp:Label></span>
    </div>   
    <div id="divRightWrapper" class="rightWrapperDiv" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img id="imgCaseGlobalReports" runat="server" alt="" src="~/Images/Replacements/IncidentReports.png"/>
    </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

I want to hide and load different ascx

aspx.vb:

```
       Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()

            If Not IsPostBack Then
                GenerateDataSets()
                GenerateLabels()
                GenerateLinks()
                GenerateControls()
                GenerateOther()
            End If

        End Sub

        Private Sub RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()
            Try
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("SessionID")) Then
                    m_SessionID = Request.QueryString("SessionID")
                    m_qrptTOD = Request.QueryString("qrptTOD")
                ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("SessionID")) Then
                    m_SessionID = Session("SessionID")
                End If


                If m_qrptTOD = "tod" Then

                    Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Page.FindControl("/Controls/Reports/rptReport.ascx").Visible = False

                    Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptTimeOfDay.ascx")))
                End If



            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub

 Protected Sub GenerateLinks()
        Dim subTreeStatisticalReport As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("StatisticalReport")
        Dim subTreeIncidentComparisons As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentComparisons")
        Dim subTreeGeographicLocations As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("GeographicLocations")

        Dim statTimeOfDayNode As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("TimeofDay")
        Dim statTrendsNode As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Trends")
        Dim statTopSevenIncidents As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Top7Incidents")
        Dim statIncidentPerCategory As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentsPerCategory")
        Dim compIncidentLoss As RadTreeNode = subTreeIncidentComparisons.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentLoss")
        Dim GeoMaps As RadTreeNode = subTreeGeographicLocations.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Maps")




        statTimeOfDayNode.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptTOD=tod")
    End Sub
```

Comment: FindControl works by matching the `Name` property, not the relative path to the source file. You have it right in the first call to FindControl, but the second one is incorrect.

Comment: Actually, it matches the `id` attribute value not `Name`.

Comment: Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent") till here is working fine but how can I set the ascx visible to false

Comment: Where is the `rptReport` control in your code? Could you show it please?

Comment: I modified my question... my rptReport is ascx that sitting in this path: "/Controls/Reports/rptReport.ascx"